# Accessing typing.Literal values

Tags: python, python-typing

How can the literals of a `typing.Literal` be accessed (and iterated over)?

For context, this is to avoid having to define the list of literals twice.

Comment: See also: [Looping through literals not typed correctly #9230](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9230)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) can be used to that end.

Comment: Some more details on *how* it would be used would improve this answer.